# Tomato substitute in italian dishes?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes, yogurt

I'm looking for some delicious Italian dishes,but have to avoid tomatoes.  What can be used as an alternate to tomatoes?

Using Google, I found Red Pepper Pasta Sauce, and Cream Sauce.

I have also heard that yogurt is a good substitute for tomato.  Can yogurt be a replacement in Italian dishes?

Comment: Questions about substitutions do a lot better if you link specific recipes.

Comment: Are you looking for tomato substitute in Italian dishes that use tomatoes, or just for Italian dishes without tomatoes?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, Italy is a country whose cuisine is defined regionally.  It varies quite widely.  While tomatoes are common throughout Italy, there are plenty of Italian dishes that do not use tomato.  Any advice about substitutions would be better provided if you have a specific dish in mind.  I can't see yogurt substituting for tomato.  While yogurt might provide the acidity that a tomato has, it also as a lactic component that would probably alter most dishes that called for tomato.  It could be delicious, but it would be different from the original intention.